# Separar fones fixos de móveis para acrescentar nono dígito

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Eu tenho uma planilha com quase 60 mil linhas, com 3 colunas:
Nome | Fone 1 | Fone 2

Nas duas colunas fone tenho números de telefones fixos e móveis e para mim a lógica é simples: Fone fixo é um número MENOR que 8 digitos. Na lógica a fórmula  é "se o número for menor que tal; coloque o nono dígito; se não só copie o número". Mas, não estou conseguindo

`=SE((F1>E4);D4&" "&E4;D4&" 9"&E4)`

Onde "D4" é o código de área.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como assim "não funciona"? O que exatamente acontece de errado? Você deve informar o erro que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1):

O telefone celular antigo também tem 8 dígitos, por isso está tendo essa dificuldade.

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
=SE(F1<55555555;D4&" "&E4;D4&" 9"&E4)
```

Sendo o F1 o númro do celular.

Sugiro porém, após ter esses dados, copiar e colar valores e utilizar a formatação condicional, deixando somente os número, sem espaços.

```
[>9999999999]"("##") "#-####-####; "("##") "####-####
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solução

Você pode utilizar Regex como função do VBA para validar isto.

### Regex

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

#### Expressão

A expressão para encontrar números de celular é a seguinte: `^[6|7|8|9](?:\d{7}|\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4})$`

Em que encontra números que começam com 6,7,8 e 9 e possuam 7 dígitos após iniciar com estes números ou 3 dígitos - (hífen) 4 dígitos.

> Obs.: Em São Paulo os números que iniciam com 5 são híbridos entre telefonia fixa e móvel. ([teleco](http://www.teleco.com.br/num_cel.asp)). Portanto, não há uma regra clara para os números que iniciam com 5.

O [demo do Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zUH2AX/2) pode ser visto e o [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ddzmOEb-t1HD1F6y) também.

### UDF (User Defined Function) no Excel VBA

#### Código

Primeiro insira esta função em um módulo.

```
Function ValidarCelular(Myrange As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^[6|7|8|9](?:\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{4})$"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Trim(Myrange.Value)
        strReplace = "9" & strInput

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                ValidarCelular = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
            Else
                ValidarCelular = Myrange.Value
            End If
    End If
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' Tratamento de Erro
    ValidarCelular= CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

#### Resultado

O teste foi feito com dados de validação na coluna A e inserindo a função `=ValidarCelular(A1)` na coluna B.

[image: Resultado]

#### Explicação Código

1. Cria a função `ValidarCelular` com `MyRange` como variável de entrada, ou seja, uma célula de variável de entrada.
2. Adiciona o padrão da Regex em `strPattern`
3. A entrada do Regex é `strInput`, que utiliza a função `Trim()` para remover os espaços em branco no início e fim.
4. O `strReplace` é a string que substituirá o que está na célula, caso seja um número de celular. Adicionando o número 9 na frente com `"9" & strInput`