# Pular dígitos ao executar

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com um problema, peguei aqui mesmo um script para inserir  o nono dígito se o telefone iniciar com 6,7,8,9..

```
Function ValidarCelular(Myrange As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^[6|7|8|9](?:\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{4})$"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Trim(Myrange.Value)
        strReplace = "9" & strInput

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                ValidarCelular = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
            Else
                ValidarCelular = Myrange.Value
            End If
    End If
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' Tratamento de Erro
    ValidarCelular= CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Porém eu preciso que a função pule os dois primeiros dígitos (o DDD) e faça a verificação do número a partir do terceiro dígito, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você utilizou esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262274/75104, então para mais informações sobre o código, refira a resposta dada.

## Regex

É necessária uma Regex nova, em que a [demo do Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zUH2AX/5) pode ser vista aqui.

Regex: `^\(*\d{2}\)*\s*[6|7|8|9](?:\d{7}|\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4})$`

## Código

Portanto o código se torna:

```
Function ValidarCelular(Myrange As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^\(*\d{2}\)*\s*[6|7|8|9](?:\d{7}|\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4})$"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Trim(Myrange.Value)
        strReplace = "9" & strInput

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                ValidarCelular = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
            Else
                ValidarCelular = Myrange.Value
            End If
    End If
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' Tratamento de Erro
    ValidarCelular= CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```